# Share wifi connection from macbook to airport express

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing, airport

I'm trying to do the following setup:

**Internet modem/router** -> (wifi)  -> **Macbook** -> (ethernet) -> **Airport express** ->(wifi) ->  **various devices**.

Is it possible to share internet from a MB to an airport express through ethernet?

My MB is a MacbookPro retina from Mid 2012

As to why i'm doing this: I don't have access to the internet modem ( can't plug anything to it), so i'm trying to spread wifi to the rest of my apartment any ways I can. Any other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to **System Preferences -> Sharing**.
2. Enable **Internet Sharing**.
3. Set **Share your connection from** to *Wi-Fi*
4. set the **To Computers using** to  *Ethernet*.
5. **Connect** the ethernet cable from Macbook to your airport's **Ethernet WAN port** (Dotted circle).
6. That's it.

Comment: I was plugging the ethernet in the wrong port on the Airport Express.
Now i see the AE in the airport utility. Looks like internet sharing is not working i'll look into that.